# Cannot access website but others can

Tags: windows, networking, local-area-network, internal-dns

My problem is that, I have just set up a server on my internal LAN and now it is in a datacenter. Everyone else can access the server and use it as normal. I however, cannot.

When I ping the domain name that the server was set up on, I get an internal IP, that is not active on my network and was not set up on the server while it was internal.

I have run LanSpy to find this IP but it cannot and neither can an arp request.

I have looked in my hosts file (Im using Windows 10) and its not there. I have looked at internal DNS on my router (which it cannot be this as other users on the LAN can access the server) and it wasn't there.

Can anyone think of anything else I could have missed. Im sure its a local config issue but I have looked everywhere and now I am baffled.

Comment: You can try to clear dns-cache in your pc and see if you are using the same dns server as others in your LAN. Try changing dns server to something else (like google dns) and check with nslookup if it still returns the same ip.

Comment: OK thats strange. It worked \o/. With Googles DNS, nslookup found it and now the website loads. Can you put your comment as a solution so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clear dns-cache in your pc and see if you are using the same dns server as others in your LAN.

You can also try changing your computers dns server to something else (like google dns) and check with `nslookup` if it still returns the same ip.

Comment: @AnthonyBroadbent, no problem, you are welcome! May be you should investigate further to find out what the problem with your current dns was.